# Why does sibling element align at the top?

Tags: css

I have a header with a structure along the lines:

```
<div class=wrapper>
   <div id="header">[insert divs html]</div>
   <div id="wordpressmenu">[insert divs html]</div>
   <div id="Social_Media_Menu">[insert divs html]</div>
</div>
```

The social media menu is new - I just added it this afternoon. Previously the Wordpress menu and logo (logo is within header div) were aligned right above my main menu. Since adding the social media menu, which has larger images, the wordpress menu and logo are now aligned incorrectly - they align with the top of the social media nav images.

I'd like to align wordpress menu where it was previously - the bottom. The two images below show this:

How it used to be (Correct alignment)
[image]

Then added the div Social Media Menu
[image]

Now there is a gap between the bottom of the logo and the main menu. There is also a gap between the original orange colored menu and the main nav.

Why is it doing this? I've tried setting the properties of the wordpress nav (The orange nav) and the social media nav to display: inline and given them fixed widths. No luck.

Can anyone see how to remove this gap so that the space between the main nav and the logo and orange nav are as they were before adding the social media buttons?

Website here (I honestly do not know which CSS to include)
http://tinyurl.com/c8djrvr

Comment: Josh I voted to close my previous question. I believe that it was too long and unclear. I attempted to clarify what exactly asking with this question instead

Comment: @DougFirr: Why not just edit your original question?

Comment: @DougFirr Alright, retracted my close vote.. Voted to close your other question as a duplicate of this one

Comment: Cheers Josh, apologies for the duplicate

Comment: @Chris fresh start I guess. I wanted to approach this attempt from the point of confusion thus: Why is a sibling element taking on what appears to be the dimension of the element next to it (By aligning with it's height). And, how do I prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a quick-and-dirty fix, `margin-top: -38px` on `#social` probably gets you there, or close. Or use a combination of negative top margins on #social and `#wpmenu` until you've got exactly what you want.

It's lining up where it is because you have a 130px height set on #header — the tops of the #social and #wpmenu divs are lining up right along the bottom edge of that, as they should. #header doesn't grow to contain the slightly larger height (188px including top padding) of the logo image, it stays at the set 130px height. The logo is visible because `overflow: visible` is the default on `div` elements. I've illustrated this by adding rgba background colors to #header and #social via the Chrome dev tools. (.2 opacity green on #social, .2 opacity orange on #header).

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Rwwl that is definitely helpful and I may go that route. Would be nice to understand why the wpmenu div is aligning up there though. Gonna leave the question open a little longer.

Comment: Explained above. It sounds like you may need to get more familiar with all the info about how stuff is laying out that's shown to you in the browser dev tools. (And I'm not trying to be snarky there, either — everyone has to at some point!)

Comment: Excellent! I just edited it a little further to be clearer about why your logo img+top padding = 188px tall but its containing div #header is still only 130px tall.

Comment: So strictly speaking it'd be better practice to adjust the height of the header to 188px, without using overflow? Part confusion comes from inheriting CSS from a CMS but I guess that's what most folk come across - inherited websites. I think you're right about getting to grips with browser dev tools - once I understand the properties a little better I should do OK

Comment: Well, I couldn't say it's necessarily better practice to use a fixed height at all on the header in this case. If writing this from scratch my approach would probably be to avoid setting a fixed height on #header at all, float it left, keep floating #social and #wpmenu right (all inside a common container that clears contained floats — lots of resources about that online), and use top margins on #social and #wpmenu to get them right where you want them...

Comment: ...or, go ahead and define exact dimensions for the container, give it position:relative, and position #social and #wpmenu absolutely, off the bottom. So many ways to skin HTML/CSS cats. In a fixed-width/non-responsive scenario, the easiest approach for the writer is generally best.

Answer (score 1):

That guy aligns that way because

- the menu is a `float:right`, and block (`display:block`) floating elements tend to stick to the top.
- the logo is wrapped in an `<a>` tag, and both are inline, so they respect the line-height on the header.
- the social buttons force up that header's height, so all the elements go up

To be honest it's not really that way and the coding should be a little semantic, but it's pretty much what is doing.

**Fix**

```
#social{ 
    position:relative; 
    margin-top:-36px 
} /* I hope I got the alignment right */
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I never knew that default behavior in float was for elements to align at the top

Comment: Also not sure why position relative was needed there? But it works, cheers!

Comment: For some reason it collapsed margins with `#main-menu`, not sure what happened there, but when I added it, it jumped a few pixels. Weird, it's not happening now... If it stays that way you don't need it.